# How to get the Class owner of an instance used as an attribute of another class (owner) in Java?

Tags: java, class, object, oop, attributes

Here is an example to explain:

```
public class Class1 { 
    //Constructor + some code
} 
public class Class2 { 
    Class1 class1 ; 
    //Constructor + Setters
} 
public class Main { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Class1 class1 = new Class1(); 
        Class2 class2 = new Class2(); 
        class2.setClass(class1) ;
    }
}
```

Can I get the instance class2 from the instance class1? If not, is there any other implementation so that I can get the instance class2 from the instance class1?

Comment: Please don't bunch up `}` at the end of lines. It makes your code needlessly hard to read.

Comment: You can pass the `Class2` instance to `Class1`'s constructor: `Class2 class2 = new Class2(); Class1 class1 = new Class1(class2);` - now you have access to your class2 instance inside of a class1 instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a [chicken and egg problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_or_the_egg) since you have a circular dependency between `Class1` and `Class2`. Have you considered introducing a third/common class which contains the common logic? This could then be injected into both.

```java
public class CommonStuff {
   // common methods
}

public class Class1 {
   private final CommonStuff common;   
   public Class1(CommonStuff common) { this.common = common; }

   // methods here which make calls to common 
   // but also do custom Class1 specific stuff
}

public class Class2 {
   private final CommonStuff common;
   public Class2(CommonStuff common) { this.common = common; }

   // methods here which make calls to common 
   // but also do custom Class2 specific stuff
}

public class Main { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        CommonStuff common = new CommonStuff();
        Class1 class1 = new Class1(common); 
        Class2 class2 = new Class2(common); 
        class1.foo();
        class2.bar();
    }
}
```